# bitcoin transaction unconfirmed requires Proof Of Funds

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

my supplier was trying to send me money as a bitcoin transaction but apparently it was flagged as high risk and set to UNCONFIRMED and requires Proof Of Funds.
Here are the details i was given

I can see that you have a pending transaction from JPY 500 for an amount of 2.13BTC to  wallet: 3KRmE6KiqCKggvvg7VjR7bhc7bVru3EzGB.

image.png
[![Image containing transaction details][1]][1]
The Bitcoin Transaction is 13ngFMYpYQvczL78VTh84aiv5Wc3PSTjjf

As you can see this transaction is still unconfirmed as it has been flagged by our risk & compliance department.

In order to finalize this transaction you will be required to provide proof of funds which should amount to 20% of the amount pending to be received to your BTC balance.

I would like to know

1. if this is a legitimate state?
2. how long will the transaction remain unconfirmed if i do nothing, ie will it just disappear?
3. what i have to do to get the transaction as confirmed and would it be advisable to have an authorised company to do it for me?

if you need more information, please do not hesitate to contact me, i am am clueless as to how these things work.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S6Xf.png

Comment: a) I don’t see any transactions attempting to pay funds to 13ngFMYpYQvczL78VTh84aiv5Wc3PSTjjf, b) none of the things you write make sense. It sounds to me that someone is trying to scam you, and you should read the topic RedGrittyBrick linked